# let you know a couple of facts OR bring couple of facts to your notice

Tags: expressions, writing, writing-style

Which of the following is more appropriate / polite?

I would like to bring a couple of facts (or things?) to your notice.
OR
I would like to let you know a couple of facts.

Please advise.

Comment: As indicated by the answers, this is writing advice, and off-topic as such.

Comment: I don't see the word "advice" anywhere in the FAQ.  Moreover, I believe nuances of word and phrases - i.e., how certain words or phrases are perceived by listeners - would fall under "usage" or "word choice," both clearly _within_ the scope of the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

While speaking it may well depend upon your tone. In writing, *let you know a couple of facts*, sounds more authoritative/accusative compared to *bring to your notice*.

Alternatively, *bring to your attention*, may be appropriate when dealing with seniors in the hierarchy.

One of the single word for the above phrase can be [accentuate](http://thesaurus.com/browse/accentuate).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are writing to someone it's really important to use words that sound polite. So it would be better sounding to the reader if you use "I would like to bring a couple of facts to your *kind* notice/attention".

Comment: I would say "kind notice" sounds rather Indian. It is like the good old question: "What is your good name?" Such statements sound like showing off as polite!

Comment: Please take your time to proofread your posts. Textspeak is completely unacceptable on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with check123.  "Facts" can have a harsh, accusatory tone which could put the listener on the defensive.  "Things" is usually a vague word to avoid, especially in writing, but it can be an acceptable way of toning down "facts," if the speaker wants to avoid sounding belligerent.

Yet there are other ways to accomplish the same thing.  You could avoid the word "you" as well:

*Let me state the facts...*

or even,

*Please allow me to give the facts...*

also sound a bit more polite, and less confrontational.